# Python Threading/ThreadPool implementation

Tags: python, multithreading, threadpool, python-multithreading

I have the following two snippets showing the power of threading and was wondering what the difference is for each implementation.

```
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool

def threadInfiniteLoop(passedNumber):
    while 1:
        print passedNumber

if __name__ == '__main__':
    packedVals={
        'number':[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
    }
    pool = ThreadPool(len(packedVals['number']))
    pool.map(func=threadInfiniteLoop,iterable=packedVals['number'])
```

and

```
import threading

def threadLoop(numberPassed):
    while 1:
        print numberPassed

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for number in range(10):
        t = threading.Thread(target=threadLoop, args=(number,))
        t.start()
```

What is the difference between the two snippets and their initialization's of each thread? Is there a benefit of one over the other and what would be a desirable situation where one would be more applicable than the other?

Comment: I think `ThreadPool` is much more readable and you can always be sure you didn't started 9000 threads.

Answer (score 0):

There's not much difference when you want to start a thread that runs forever.

Normally, you use a thread pool when your program continually creates new finite tasks to perform "in the background" (whatever that means).

Creating and destroying threads is relatively expensive, so it makes more sense to have a small number of threads that stick around for a long time, and then use those threads over and over again to perform the background tasks.  That's what a thread pool does for you.

There's usually no point in creating a thread *pool* when all you want is a single thread that never terminates.

Comment: How about for the case of wanting to run multiple threads indefinitely in a while loop?

Comment: @George52098, If you're asking about starting an indefinite number of threads, where each thread does some small thing and then it dies, then those small things are what I was talking about when I said "tasks":  It's better to use a thread pool to do that kind of work because the thread pool does not have to create a new thread for each new task.  The cost of creating a new thread for each new task can substantially outweigh the cost of actually doing the tasks.